# Show that the number of leaves in a tree equals to $\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{v\in V}|\text{deg}(v)-2|+1\right).$

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, trees

> Show that the number of leaves in tree equals to.
>   $$\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{v\in V}|\text{deg}(v)-2|+1\right).$$

I know the theorems,

- For any graph, $\sum_{v\in V} \text{deg}(v) = 2 \left\vert E \right\vert$  holds.
- For any tree, $\left\vert V \right\vert=\left\vert E \right\vert + 1$  holds.

The difficult thing for me to approach about the expression of the given problem is that I must care about "absolute value" expression. $\quad i.g. \quad \left\vert \text{deg}(v)- 2 \right\vert$

Because, if there is Not the absolute value expression, below

$$\sum_{i=1}^{k} \text{deg}(v_i) - 2 = 2\left\vert E \right\vert - 2k.$$

but, as absolute symbol is, I must consider each cases.

I need a hint to approach this problem, please.

Comment: The only vertices for which $\deg(v)-2<0$ are leaves. I suppose you can write the summation in two parts: leaves and nonleaves.

Answer (score 3):

Let $V_1$ be the vertices of degree $1$, i.e. the set of leaves. Then 
\begin{align}
\sum_{v\in V}|\text{deg}(v)-2|&=\sum_{v\in V-V_1}(\text{deg}(v)-2)+\sum_{v\in V_1}|1-2|\\
&=\sum_{v\in V-V_1}\text{deg}(v)-2(|V|-|V_1|)+|V_1|\\
&=\sum_{v\in V}\text{deg}(v)-2(|V|-|V_1|)\\
&=2|E|-2(|E|+1)+2|V_1|=-2+2|V_1|.
\end{align}
Hence
$$|V_1|=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{v\in V}|\text{deg}(v)-2|+1\right).$$